# Solve this system of linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve a system of linear congruences, here is a copy and paste of the exact question:

> Question 2.
>
> (a) Show that Z12 is not a field.
>
> (b) Solve $7x \equiv 4 \mod(19)$, $4x \equiv 2 \mod (12)$, and $3x \equiv 9 \mod (12)$.

I am happy with my answer to part a).
But I cant seem to solve for part b).
I feel the idea is to get all 3 congruences into the form $x \equiv a \mod (n)$ and then use the Chinese remainder theorem.

for $7x \equiv 4 \mod(19)$  find $7^{-1} \rightarrow x \equiv 7^{-1} \times 4 \mod(19)$

and $3x \equiv 9 \mod (12)$ is congruent to as $x \equiv 3 \mod (4)$

However I don't think $4x \equiv 2 \mod (12)$ has a solution. i.e. there is no multiple of $4 \mod (12)$ with remainder 2.

I maybe missing something. Any tips would help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you were to suppose that there was a solution then $4x\equiv 2\pmod{12}\implies 4x-2=12k\implies 2x-1\equiv 6k$ but $2x-1$ is odd while $6k$ is even, but we know that a number cannot be simultaneously odd and even, it must be one or the other.  As written, you are correct that there is no solution.

Comment: Yes thats the same conclusion that I came to, I will email my professor. Thanks for confirming.